# Правильно ли написано, какие есть ошибки?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые, вводные-слова

Понятие красоты очень субъективно... Как по мне, ничего для меня привлекательного в этих лицах нет. Однако, видно что их черты лица правильно сформированы. Это вызывает, на уровне инстинктов, некую приемственность.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы написала так:

Понятие красоты очень субъективно... Как по мне, ничего привлекательного в этих лицах нет. Однако видно, что они правильно сформированы. Это вызывает на уровне инстинктов некую преемственность.

**Объяснения**

I. *Как **по мне**, ничего **для меня**...* Неоправданный повтор.

II. *Однако, видно что...* —> Однако видно, что...
[Однако](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_504&layout=item#:%7E:text=%40%20%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%C2%AB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%C2%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B5,%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C.) — в начале предложения запятой не отделяется.
В сложноподчиненном предложении перед "что" нужна запятая.

III. *...что их черты лица правильно сформированы.*
Мне кажется, что логично написать "их лица правильно сформированы" — ли́ца, а не черты. Но "в этих лицах" уже было, поэтому "они".
[сформировать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), *кого-что*
**4. *только страд. прич. прош.*** Приобрести какую-либо форму, вид в процессе развития, роста. *Деревце хорошо сформировано.*

IV. Из орфографического словаря: [пр**е**е́мственность](http://orfo.info/word/preemstvennosty.php).

V. В последнем предложении (смысл его, правда, мне не совсем понятен) я бы не стала ставить запятые.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли мне)

Comment: @user202341 Тогда примите ответ, то есть отметьте галочкой. А в будущем Вы сможете не только принимать **один** из ответов на свой вопрос, но и отмечать стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх **все** полезные вопросы и ответы.